# Dynamic Database Selection in PHP Mongodb

Tags: php, mongodb

Not able to select the `database` and collection dynamically. Read all the solutions but not working for me. `selectDB` function not working. It's working only with the static data.

I want to select the database from the configuration file and also select the collections dynamically.

```
$username='abcd';
$password='efgh';
$m = new MongoDB\Client("mongodb://abcd@127.0.0.1:28015/ijkl", array("username" => $username, "password" => $password));

$db = $m->ijkl;
```

but I want to have it like

```
$username='abcd';
$password='efgh';
$m = new MongoDB\Client("mongodb://abcd@127.0.0.1:28015/ijkl", array("username" => $username, "password" => $password));

$l1="ijkl";
$db = $m->$l1;
```

Expecting to work with dynamic database selection.

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"? There is no `selectDB` function in your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally it's working

```
$m = new MongoDB\Client("mongodb://".$mongo_username."@".$mongo_ip.":".$mongo_port."/".$mongo_db, array("username" => $mongo_username, "password" => $mongo_password));


 if(!empty($db = $m->$mongo_db))
 {
     $collection = "test";

   if(!empty($collection = $db->$collection))
   {

    $cursor =$collection->find(array("status"=>0), ['limit' => 10,'skip'=>10]);

     foreach ($cursor as $document) {

        echo "<b>ID is:</b>";
        echo $id=$document["_id"];
        echo "<br>";
        echo "<b>Link is:</b>";
        echo $link=$document["Link"];
        echo "<br>";
        echo "<b>Status is:</b>";
        echo $status=$document["status"];
        echo "<br>";
        echo "<b>Label is:</b>";
        echo $label=$document["Label"];
        echo "<br>";


    }
   }
   else
   {
       echo "Not able to select the collection!";
   }
 }
 else
 {
     echo "Not able to select the database!";
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use mongodb client repo from packagist. 
You can install it via [composer](https://getcomposer.org/)

```
$ composer require mongodb/mongodb
```

in your root directory, create file for example app.php

```
<?php

require 'vendor/autoload.php';

$databases = [
 'db1'=> [
    'db' => 'testdb1',
    'username' => 'user',
    'password' => 'pass',
    ...
 ], 
  'db2'=> [...],
  ...
];
$seletected = 'db1';

$database = $databases[$selected];

$client = new MongoDB\Client(
    "mongodb+srv://{$database['username']}:{$database['password']}@<cluster-address>/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority"
);


$db = $client->{$database['db']};
```

Comment: I'm doing it in core PHP and in windows platform. How it will gonna help me?

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Comment: @DipakChatterjee shoud have composer install in your pc, and you can install it.

Comment: The point is if you can see my code I've done the same thing which you suggested. But it's only working when I mentioned the database explicitly. I want to use a variable instead of that. I think you did not understand my question.

Comment: @DipakChatterjee i created an array of all database and select one, by the select variable

Answer (score 0):

replace $db = $m->$l1 to $db = $m->{$l1}

```
$username='abcd';
$password='efgh';
require 'vendor/aoutoload.php';
$m = new MongoDB\Client("mongodb://abcd@127.0.0.1:28015/ijkl", array("username"=> $username, "password" => $password));

$l1="ijkl";

$db = $m->{$l1};
```